# Calling TikTok Pixel events in React

Tags: reactjs, tiktok

I am trying to include a TikTok pixel in an application. According to their [docs](https://ads.tiktok.com/marketing_api/docs?id=1701890973258754), I'm supposed to include their base code in the `<head>` tag and call the corresponding event whenever I'd like it to track, for example: `ttq.track('CompleteRegistration')` when a registration is complete in the application.

How I do this in a React/Redux application?

For example, we have a `HTML.jsx` where I can include the pixel script in either the `<head>` tag (or just before the `</body>` tag in order prevent page rendering:

```
<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `the-pixel-code-here`, // this sets up the ttq variable
}} />
```

But in my child components where I want an event to fire, their docs say to call `ttq.track('CompleteRegistration')` so let's say, I do something like this:

```
export const completeRegistration = (somePayload) => {
    // do all the things that you need to do to complete a registration
    ...
    const response = server.post('/registration', somePayload)
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        ...
        ttq.track('CompleteRegistration')
    } 
    ...
}

export const RegFormSubmitButton = () => {
    return (<button onClick={() => completeRegistration(this.props.somePayload)}>Submit</button>)
}
```

But instead, I get an error saying:

```
Cannot find name 'ttq'
'ttq' is not defined
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: did you try adding their script in head tag of  `public/index.html`?

Comment: Yes, I have. Still doesn't work.

Comment: check if `window.ttq` works. also console.log(window.ttq) in head tag immediately after the base code.

Comment: Printing out `window.ttq` or `ttq` immediately after the base code in the head tag AND in my React action file both print out the correct object. I forgot to mention that I have linting rule `no-undef` enabled and this is a Typescript file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of libraries generally add a global variable, which can be accessed on `window` object like `window.ttq`

The code snippet can also be added in `src/index.js` instead of `public/index.html` (or added to a separate file and imported into `index.js` file). Note that the script initializing will be relatively late in this case, only after react is initialized.

Coming to typescript warning, we can extend the Window interface to include `ttq` property, or simply type cast `window` like `(window as any).ttq` wherever you have to use the library.

(*Answered the question to avoid unnecessary attention.*)

Answer (score 0):

Coming late but to expand on the last answer, if you want to extend the window  and not have to cast to any, stick this at the top of your file, or in your type declaration file:

```
declare const window: {
  ttq: {
    track: (eventName: string, data: Record<string, unknown>) => void
  }
}
```